# Python ordered combination of numbers?

Tags: python

I am looking to write something that will display an ordered list of all possible combinations. It can start at something like

11-AA
11-AB
11-AC

...and eventually end at...

59-YZ
59-ZZ

I would also like it if the first part of the number can only be between 1-5. I have been working with itertools, but I am having a hard time generating this specific sort of thing. I can generate all possible combinations of 4 letters repeated twice, but I'm having issues getting the dash in, and telling the program that "Hey, you can only chose between 1 and 4 for the first number".

```
import itertools

perms = itertools.product('ABCD', repeat=2)

for perm in perms:
    print('The possible combinations are', perm)
```

There is the code for that. This doesn't HAVE to use itertools, that is just what I was familar with.

EDIT: The first answer was precisely what I needed. I didn't like what the itertools was doing because of the commas, but the little snippet you showed me is magic. Thank you.

To answer the question, a loop just seemed less clean? I also just discovered the itertools, and am probably enjoying it too much.

Comment: As a side note, you want the values to end at `59-ZZ`, and you want the first part to only be 1-5, so I assume "Hey, you can only chose between 1 and 4 for the first number" is a typo and you meant "… 1 and 5…", right?

Answer (score 7):

Just do this in equal pieces. One character has to be `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, or `5`; the second can be any digit; the third must be `-`, the last two must be `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`, so:

```
perms = itertools.product('12345', '0123456789', '-', 'ABCD', 'ABCD')
```

And then, to join them up into strings:

```
print('The possible combinations are:')
for perm in perms:
    print(''.join(perm))
```

---

This starts with `10-AA`, not `11-AA`. There's no way to end with `59` if you start with `11` (assuming you want the numbers in order).

---

I originally left the `-` out and joined up each string with `format`, but I think this is slower. It's also at least twice as fast on every Python version I have handy. (The cost of a 1-length loop in C is trivial, as is building a 5-tuple vs. a 4-tuple; the cost of `format` vs. `join` is not.)

You could also `product` up a `range(11, 60)` and a `product('ABCD', repeat=2)`, then flatten it with `chain`, then `format` each one. While that's *conceptually* simpler, it's going to be a *lot* harder to read, and is about as slow as the flat `format` version.

Anyway, in 64-bit python.org 3.3.2 on OS X 10.9:

```
In [1189]: %timeit collections.deque((''.join(perm) for perm in itertools.product('1234', '1234567890', '-', 'ABCD', 'ABCD')), maxlen=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop

In [1190]: %timeit collections.deque(('{}{}-{}{}'.format(*perm) for perm in itertools.product('1234', '1234567890', 'ABCD', 'ABCD')), maxlen=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 359 µs per loop
```

Comment: Can the `-` not be dropped and just have `print('{0}{1}-{2}{3}'.format(*perm)` or similar...

Comment: @JonClements: Sure (in fact, that was my first version…), but I think this is actually simpler, and I doubt the performance will be much different either way.

Comment: @abarnert I actually like this version - I think it is much clearer and I prefer it... it's just that internal nagging that the `-` really shouldn't be there as it's formatting and not really "part of the product" :)

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, I also thought about doing the left part as `range(10, 60)` and the right part as `product('ABCD', repeat=2)`, but then you need a `product` of the two parts, and you again need `format`.